# Spark - sort the element based on more than one field using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a JavaRDD with Person details, now i wanted to sort the JavaRDD element based on Age field first then Name field.

Sample Input is:

```
Age, Name, Country
33,Jack,USA
24,Sam,USA
31,Jack,USA
```

My output should be something like this:

```
Age, Name, Country
24,Sam,USA
31,Jack,USA
33,Jack,USA
```

How do i achieve this using Sortby transformation?

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: Take a look at [Producing a sorted wordcount with Spark](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56641/producing-a-sorted-wordcount-with-spark)

Comment: You can just create the JavaPairRDD from the input with key as age and value can be other columns and just sort by the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite ugly in java (thats where scalas case classes come really handy) but you can do it by creating bean for for the record and implementing comparable. Now just use sortBy method with identity key function:

```java
    JavaRDD<Record> data = sc.parallelize(
                Lists.newArrayList(
                        new Record(33, "Jack", "USA"),
                        new Record(24, "Sam", "USA"),
                        new Record(24, "Dan", "USA"),
                        new Record(31, "Jack", "USA")));
        JavaRDD<Record> sorted 
            = data.sortBy(rec -> rec, true, data.partitions().size());
        System.out.println(sorted.collect());

    //define bean
    class Record implements Serializable, Comparable<Record> {
        private int age;
        private String name;
        private String country;

        public Record(int age, String name, String country) {
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.country = country;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Record o) {
            int compAge = Integer.compare(this.age, o.age);
            if (compAge != 0) return compAge;
            else return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return new ToStringBuilder(this)
                    .append("age", age)
                    .append("name", name)
                    .append("country", country)
                    .toString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's not ugly, that's verbose. Having raw data is not good design, having objects representing concepts is cooler. I agree Scala saves you all the boilerplate though. Anyway, this is the answer

Comment: @user52045 Thanks for the answer. Will it work good for 100s of millions of data too?

Comment: How much you can sort would mostly depend on your cluster. But I'm pretty sure that if you can sort your data in spark with any method this will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will perform the task as required ->

```
JavaRDD<String> people = sc.textFile("/home/hduser/input");

// The schema is encoded in a string
String schemaString = "Age  Name    Country";

// Generate the schema based on the string of schema
List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
for (String fieldName : schemaString.split("    ")) {
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName,
DataTypes.StringType, true));
}
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

// Convert records of the RDD (people) to Rows.
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = people.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
public Row call(String record) throws Exception {
String[] fields = record.split(",");
return RowFactory.create(fields[0], fields[1].trim(),
fields[2].trim());
}
});

// Apply the schema to the RDD.
DataFrame peopleDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);

// Register the DataFrame as a table.
peopleDataFrame.registerTempTable("people");

// SQL can be run over RDDs that have been registered as tables.
DataFrame results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM people").sort("Age");

results.show();
```

Comment: Loved the sort method from Spark SQL, can we able to sort with more than one column?